# out of memory error on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, out-of-memory

in my app i have one layout and i set background for root view of it(relative layout)

```
    android:background="@drawable/paris"
```

when i test app on my mobile(xpreia z),nexus 5 emulator, or tablet emulators everything is ok but run this app on nexus s emulator nexus ,nexus 4 emulator and... stopped wtih out of memory error.
my image that set to background only has 1.4 m size.

1-if heap size for every app is almost 12m
why my app that have only one image with 1.4m size and little code and library generate out of memory error?

2-What should I do to avoid this error and be certain that my app run in all devices without out of memory error?

thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Could it be some density problem? Maybe the device is scaling the image and reaches an `oom` ? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly happens due to loading Large Image files which overflows assigned application memory by Android. It is mostly advised to load scale down versions into memory and re-use it from cache.

There is a very nice [article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) on official Android website with code samples.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the size that matters here is uncompressed size, not compressed size. Scale down your image to a better size.

Answer (score 1):

Think about bit per pixel, if your background is a 24bits image file (RGB), for example if your image is 1 million pixel it will take 24bits * 1,000,000 in memory.

1920*1080px image = about 2 Million Pixel

24bits * 2M = 6MB in memory